# Nova Launcher displaying wrong icons

Tags: notifications, app-icons, recents-screen, nova-launcher

I'm using the Glim icon pack with Nova Launcher and everything displays correctly on my home screen and drawer. Though in my recent apps screen and notification screen, lock screen it shows a different/incorrect icon for the app. I've reapplied the icon pack via Nova and the Icon pack itself, it doesn't fix this. How can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

<sub>Click image(s) for larger version</sub>

Comment: Which android version are you running? Are you running CyanogenMod on your device? If so - have you installed Themes via the Theme-Engine?

Comment: @benjaminS I have CM13 so android 6.0 and no Themes installed via theme bucket or any other.

Answer (score 1):

Any icon pack (not themes like Cyanogen Mod themes for example) can only apply to launchers and apps not the Android system itself.

(Except that the system supports icon packs which is not common in official ROMs.)

And Nova Launcher (like most launchers if not all of them) only displays the home screen and the app drawer, anything other than that (like recent apps, notifications, and lock screen) is controlled by the Android system not Nova Launcher.

Note: The lock screen icons can be changed by a lock screen app but not Nova Launcher.

Final answer: You can change the icons everywhere in your phone (CM13) if it has a theme engine and you install & apply an icon pack that is compatible with the theme engine or apply a compatible theme with the desired icons. (Note that you need to choose to display system icons from Nova Launcher afterwards.)